# Clean Text Rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using "open sans" font in my website. But it render unclear and dirty edges font. **IMAGE BELOW**

[image]

But i see on some another websites that they are using same open sans font but its very clean and retina ready **Image below**

[image]

Why my text edges are untidy and unclean?

ADDITIONAL: I tried disable the stylesheet codes and text rendering is clear and retina ready. But what i am missing?

Comment: Is this a programming question?  Stack Overflow is A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

Comment: I think yes, Because when i disable style sheet, font render clear and soft edges. maybe there is some bug in my stylesheet!

Comment: 3000+ lines style sheet! not possible to include!

Comment: I don't think we need the whole thing, just part that is relevant to your question.

Comment: if i know what's the relevant part making issue in my style sheet than i will not bother smart people here!

Comment: @user3109580 and this is where http://jsfiddle.net comes into play. You can also try reducing your css section by section until the text becomes clear to narrow down the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I know how to solve this...add this to your css:

```
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

I add that to ALL my web projects now. It makes the fonts looks much more crisp :)

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37LqY/1/)

Also, when using web fonts, it's a good idea to deliberately specify the font weight.

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300; /* 300 is the "light" version of the font, 400 would be "normal" */
}
```

Comment: Absolutely Right! I see in your demo that you gave font weight to make it clean and when i removed font weight, it looks same like my font ( not clean and sharp edges) You solved my problem, in some sections i never added font weight and thats why its rendering unclean font. Hats off!

Comment: header tags (`h1, h2, etc`) default to "bold" which is 700 weight I think so you gotta make sure an override that with custom fonts! :)